# tex4ht using \(...\) in moving arguments

Tags: tex4ht, robust-commands

I'm using `tex4ht` to produce HTML that contains mathematical content to be rendered using MathJax.

This question is about inline mathematical content in moving arguments, such as `\section{\(y^2\)}` and `\caption{\(y^2\)}`.

### Working minimal example

The following code compiles fine:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{$y^2$}
\end{document}
```

### Non-working minimal example

Using `\(...\)` within the moving argument makes the compilation fail:

```tex
\documentclass{article}
\begin{document}
\section{\(y^2\)}
\end{document}
```

### Compilation

For both the working, and the non-working minimum working example, I'm using the following command to compile:

```
make4ht -a debug mwe.tex "mathjax"
```

### texmf-dist/tex/generic/tex4ht/mathjax-latex-4ht.4ht

I think that this will likely come down to redefining `\AltlMath` from `mathjax-latex-4ht.4ht`, to make it robust. The default definition is:

```tex
\long\def\AltlMath#1\){\expandafter\alteqtoks{\(#1\)}\)}
```

### Question

How can I configure `AltlMath` to be robust so that `\(...\)` works within moving arguments?

Footnote: changing the .tex file is not an option :)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The MathJax configuration for TeX4ht provides command for commands that cause issues in sections: `\fixmathjaxtoc`. The problem is that some commands cause issues when they are written to the TOC file.

Try this config file:

```
\Preamble{xhtml}

\fixmathjaxtoc\(
\fixmathjaxtoc\)
\begin{document}
\EndPreamble
```

This is the result:

[image]

Comment: Ah, of course! That's wonderful, thank you so much. I do fully intend to help with the documentation of `tex4ht` once work allows. Thank you!

Comment: @cmhughes I've added this to TeX4ht sources. It would be great if you could take a look at the docs! I found that this issue is even already [described in the draft](https://www.kodymirus.cz/tex4ht-doc/Configurations.html#x8-770007.19.3)

Comment: This looks great, thanks for the link. I assume the source is still in your github. I'm hopeful to contribute to it once things calm down at work. I use make4ht and tex4ht a lot, and your help has been invaluable

Comment: @cmhughes yes, this pages is automatically generated using Github Actions from https://github.com/michal-h21/tex4ht-doc. It needs lot of work, spell checking, grammar checking, expanding sections with information from older documentation or from my answers here, for example.

Answer (score 0):

Is this helps you?

```
%%mwe.cfg
    \Preamble{html}
    \newtoks\eqtoks 
    \def\AltMath#1${\eqtoks{$#1$}% 
       \HCode{\the\eqtoks}$}
    \Configure{$}{}{}{\expandafter\AltMath}  
    \def\AltlMathI#1\){\eqtoks{\(#1\)}% 
            \HCode{\the\eqtoks}}
    \Configure{()}{\AltlMathI}{}
    \begin{document}
    \EndPreamble
```

Modified `TeX` code:

```
\section{\protect\(y^2\)}
```

It works for me....

Please excuse, if not so ....

Comment: When I place this in `mwe.cfg` and run `make4ht -m draft -a debug -c mwe.cfg mwe.tex` the document does not compile. Did it compile for you?

Comment: Sorry, please check the update ....

Comment: Thanks for looking at this. As I noted in my question: *changing the .tex file is not an option* :) I know that I can add `\protect` to all of these, but if that were an option, then I would simply change them all to `$...$`.

Comment: I read your `MWE`, I thought that you don't want to change `\(...\)` to `$...$1, but now I understood that don't want to give `\protect` too....sorry....